# Visualize mongoDb with dcJs (Meteor)

Tags: mongodb, d3.js, meteor, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm interested to visualize Meteor data (mongoDb) with dcJs. However, I can't find much information about this topic.

I recreated http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697043/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-2-Graphing using Meteor.

Without calling mongodb,

```
var data = [
    {_id: "iD1", date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
    {_id: "iD2", date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
    {_id: "iD3", date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
    {_id: "iD4", date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD5", date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD6", date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD7", date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
    {_id: "iD8", date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD9", date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD10", date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {_id: "iD11", date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
    {_id: "iD12", date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
    ];
```

The result is working fine.

[image]

By inserting and calling data from mongodb, failed.

[image]

Not sure what's missing here.

Hope to get advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is fired from the following code:

```
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;
```

It's probable that your template rendered callback is being fired before the data has been loaded from the database.

Probably the easiest way to fix it would be to put an if statement:

```
if (Dichas.find().count() !== 0) {
    ... all of the code that depends on there being data
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to debug your code if you posted the working app on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you pointed out, the data is not loaded before the template rendering. The solution is to load data 1st before rendering template, instead of at the same time! I will update at the hackpad :-)

Comment: Please don't remove your comments after someone has replied, it's polite to keep all of the information visible here so that someone else who comes across the same issue can see it.

Comment: Because the old comment was about not getting solution. So, I replaced with a more concise comment. But noted on this~! Next time, I will just left there~! Thanks a lot!!